# my page does not display all the content on android

Tags: android, html, css

I've created a simple web page and placed all main option buttons such as home, login etc. of the index page in the upper right corner of the nav panel. On a pc everything is ok but on my android these buttons on the right do not appear. In a sense that I scroll to the right but it stops at some point before the user being able to see the button options so it's virtually unusable.

What I have tried?

I've looked in the web and I found that for android you need to set up another meta in the format below

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

Although this helped a bit and the user can scroll to the right they still cannot reach the buttons. Below is an example of the page. On android when I scroll to the right it stops before reaching the buttons.

[image]

Comment: Share a log along with the View or snapshot you are talking about.

Comment: I've uploaded an example

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem. I don't know why but removing the meta tags made my browser on android to display everything on the page. Thanks anyway